# How to change the user mail without verification code

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'd like to change the mail of a user without sending/requiring a verification code.

I'm using the following command*:

```
aws cognito-idp admin-update-user-attributes \
  --user-pool-id [POOL_ID] \
  --username [COGNITO_ID] \
  --user-attributes Name=email,Value=new_mail@a.com
```

I thought the `admin-update-user-attributes` would allow a mail change without a verification process.

* Eventually I'm going to use the API, but for this quesion the AWS CLI suffices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also set the `email_verified` attribute to `true`.

The command below should work:

```
aws cognito-idp admin-update-user-attributes \
  --user-pool-id [POOL_ID] \
  --username [COGNITO_ID] \
  --user-attributes Name=email,Value=new_mail@a.com Name=email_verified,Value=true
```